# How to check if two or more programs are installed using a bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to check whether two or more programs are installed using a bash script:

```
hash foo &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    echo >&2 "foo not found."
else
    echo "foo found"
fi
```

The above script works for a single program and I want to check for multiple programs installed in a system. How can I do that?

Comment: So why don't you just copy these lines?

Comment: Do you just want to confirm whether both are found, or do you want to display the individual status of each?

Comment: @steeldriver I want to confirm whether both are installed or not and  don’t want the individual status of the programmes

Comment: @davidbaumann  I don’t want the individual status of two programs. I just want to check if two of the programs are installed or not

Comment: some thing like this `hash foo &> /dev/null || hash goo &> /dev/null` but if foo is installed and goo is not installed it still shows programs exists

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to check that *all* of them are installed, just do:

```
hash foo bar baz &>/dev/null && 
    echo "All programs installed" ||
    echo "At least one program is missing"
```

The `&>` redirects standard error and standard output to `/dev/null` so you don't print the output of `hash`. You probably only need `2>` since as far as I know, `hash` only prints to stderr, but we may as well be on the safe side.

The `&&` means that the next command will only be run if the previous one was successful. The `||` means the next command will only be run if the previous one failed. So, if one of the three (or N) programs you checked for is not installed, you will get the error message.

If you want to be told which program is not installed, use this one instead:

```
for p in foo bar baz; do 
    hash "$p" &>/dev/null && echo "$p is installed" ||
                 echo "$p is not installed"
done
```

Finally, for even more fine grained control and detailed output, you could do:

```
i=0; n=0; progs=(foo bar baz);
for p in "${progs[@]}"; do
    if hash "$p" &>/dev/null
    then
        echo "$p is installed"
        let c++
    else
        echo "$p is not installed"
        let n++
    fi
done
printf "%d of %d programs were installed.\n"  "$i" "${#progs[@]}" 
printf "%d of %d programs were missing\n" "$n" "${#progs[@]}"
```

Comment: A check and install is not installed question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298066/check-if-an-apt-get-package-is-installed-and-then-install-it-if-its-not-on-linu

Comment: @CiroSantilli I think you meant to comment on the OP, right? That doesn't seem to be addressed to me. Also, note how those approaches all assume the program name is the same as the package name. Here, we are only working with executable names and don't know what the package name will be.